# SoundPool or MediaPlayer queue

Tags: android, audio, media-player

It is possible to play sounds in queue in mediaplayer or soundpool? I have 50 sounds with duration less than one second.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect case for SoundPool. SoundPool is ideal for things like sound effects, which will typically be short (like less than a second) and plentiful (like 50), so it's exactly what you're looking for. MediaPlayer is geared more towards long media files such as background music tracks and videos, and won't be practical for 50 small files.

Comment: but how to play sound one after another(in queue)?

Comment: Ah, that's a little more involved. SoundPool doesn't really have any built in functionality to handle that, but there's a couple things you could try. One way you could do it is to run a timer, probably in a background thread, and every 900 ms or so play the next sound. The problem with this is you'd have to use the length of you longest sound to avoid truncating/overlap which might cause unwanted gaps if there's enough variation in length between your sound files.

Comment: You can also look at Brent's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663794/android-soundpool-timing), where he talks about getting the durations of each sound file and sequencing them accordingly. He uses a MediaPlayer to get the duration, which is a little wasteful and suboptimal, but it's another option.

Comment: I just discovered that SoundPool won't play any of my mp3 files which are under one second. What a nuisance.

Comment: @capcom Where did you hear that? I use a sound pool in my app and many of the sounds are shorter than one second.